# Horizontally centering two divs (unequal in width), with no wrap

Tags: css, html, centering

My page looks like this: http://ink-12.terc.edu/index.cfm
I want to get the picture (kids' drawings) on the left to follow the rest of the centered content, when the window expands:

[image]

Per the suggestions I found in other answers, I added an outer div (`#maincontent`) to hold my two divs that I want to scroll instead of wrap (`#tbltframe` and `#drawings`), and some additional coding (`overflow:auto; display:inline-block; white-space:nowrap`).

Now my page looks like this:
[image]
 http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/index.cfm

So now it doesn't wrap (great!), but it cut off my drop shadow on the right side (you can still see it on the bottom). And I need to get the main content centered again (following the centered header and footer)--similar to the first webpage I listed. After the changes, the main content aligns left. I tried adding `margin-right` and `margin-left:auto`, as well as `text-align:center`, but neither did it. I also added a min-width, which doesn't seem to do it either. I can see the drop shadow again when I change the min-width to something significantly larger (74em), then but I don't know why, because `#tbltframe` (50em) and `#drawings` (14em) = 64em total.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Suggestions to move forward with the code on either webpage I listed would be fine. Thank you!

Comment: might be a good idea to screenshot those sites in their current state. That way, someone viewing your question in the future will know what's going on and might still benefit from it.

Comment: @thomas shields, thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried to upload screenshots though, and am not allowed because I'm a new user.

Comment: upload the screenshots to http://imgur.com/ and post the links in the comments; I'll edit them in for you.

Comment: @ThomasShields, okay, thanks!  Here's the first webpage I was talking about: http://i.imgur.com/2xMsb.png and here's the second: http://i.imgur.com/4QKip.png

Comment: Dear see my answer and please let me know if this helped you or else i will change the code as per your need... thanks

Comment: @ThomasShields Thanks for uploading my screenshots for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: http://www.search-this.com/2008/08/28/lets-all-get-inline-in-a-block-in-a-block/

Have to:

Create a min-width or width on the outer div (#maincontent)

Make #maincontent a block element with display:block

Center #maincontent with text-align:center

Make the inside divs (#drawings and #tbltframe)not wrap in #maincontent with white-space:nowrap;

Make the inside divs inline block elements with display:inline-block

Then make the text inside wrap again (if you want) with white-space:normal

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below css on skeleton.css line 64

```
#maincontent {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1169px;
}
```

It will increase the width of the main content div so the images will not cut from sides..

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I'm just wondering what's going on with my math here, because my outer div (#maincontent = 64em) holds two divs (#drawings = 14em and #tbltframe1 = 50em). The math adds up, so there's no reason anything should be cut off...